# Regex: Replace semi-colons with enter key "\n"

Tags: regex

I have a string to replace semi-colons with `\n`. The requirement I have is to detect only those semi-colons that are outside HTML `<>` tags and replace them with `\n`.

I have come very close by using this regex by implementing multiple fixes.

`/((?:^|>)[^<>]*);([^<>]*(?:<|$))/g, '$1\n$2'`

The above regex works well if I input string like the below one -
`Value1;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value2</p>;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value3</p>;Value4`

The output it gives is this (which is expected and correct) - 
`Value1`
`<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value2</p>`
`<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value3</p>`
`Value4`

But fails if I input string like - `M1;M2;M3`

The output this gives is - 
`M1;M2`
`M3`

(semi-colon doesn't remove between M1 and M2).

whereas the expected output should be -

`M1`
`M2`
`M3`

Also the string can be like this too (both combined) - `M1;M2;M3;Value1;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value2</p>;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value3</p>;Value4`

The major goal is to replace all the semicolons outside HTML Tags `<>` and replace it with '\n` (enter key).

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11261546)

Comment: @Ivan this is about nested HTML tags, not something I am looking for.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript?

Comment: @HaoWu Yes. Using .replace() to replace semi-colons with \n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex associate with `.replace()` function of JavaScript:

```
/(<[^<>]*>)|;/g
```

For substitution, you may use this function:

```js
(_, tag) => tag || '\n'
```

If `(<[^<>]*>)` catches anything - which is a HTML tag, it will go into `tag` parameter, otherwise an outbound `;` must be matched.

So you can check if `tag` exists. If it exists, replace with itself, otherwise replace it with a `\n`.

```js
const text = `Value1;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value2</p>;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value3</p>;Value4

M1;M2;M3`;

const regex = /(<[^<>]*>)|;/g;

const result = text.replace(regex, (_, tag) => tag || '\n');

console.log(result);
```